# Disable comments for a user?

Tags: comments, user-access, community

Is there a way I could ban a registered user from posting comments, thus converting them to a read-only mode temporarily? Ideally I'd like this to be a set-it-and-forget-it solution (ban user for 2 days, then they are unbanned automatically 2 days later).

I have comments open to registered users only, sitewide.

I have searched thoroughly for a plugin to help me achieve this, but failed to find anything.

Comment: It should be easy to "ban" a user, but you will need an interface to manage the process. Your question does not explain how you want that to work. As is, i'd say the question is much too broad and probably "work for me for free" as well.